fecha formato bigint php
Estoy utilizando un proyecto de github llamado Kanboard. En una tabla de tareas esta la fecha de inicio y la fecha de fin, quería ver la diferencia de fechas para asi tener el tiempo que se tarda en realizar la tarea.
El problema me viene que las fechas en la base de datos(MySql) son de tipo bigint, del estilo '1709541650' que equivale a ' 08/03/2024 15:43'.
Yo accedo a la fecha de la siguiente manera:
$task['date_completed']

y tengo un retorno de un string pero seria de este estilo '1709541650'.
He probado lo siguiente:
$date1 = date("Y-m-d",$task['date_completed']);
$date2= $task['date_creation']; 
$diff = date_diff($date1, $date2) 

pero me aparece 'Expected type 'DateTimeInterface'. Found 'string'
También lo he probado restando una fecha a la otra directamente pero no da el resultado que espero.
Edit:
Añado código y valores obtenidos:
    $dateCreation = date("Y-m-d",$task['date_creation']);
                        
    $dateObject  = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', 
    $metadata["Closed_Date"]);
    $dateObject2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $dateCreation);
    $timeClosing = $dateObject->diff($dateObject2);
    $timeClosing = $timeClosing->format('%d días');
                       
?>
<?= 
    var_dump($dateObject);var_dump($dateObject2);
    $timeClosing;
?>

Y obtengo:

object(DateTime)#624 (3) {
  ["date"]=&gt;
  string(26) "2024-02-02 11:11:46.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=&gt;
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=&gt;
  string(13) "Europe/Madrid"
}
object(DateTime)#622 (3) {
  ["date"]=&gt;
  string(26) "2023-03-02 11:11:46.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=&gt;
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=&gt;
  string(13) "Europe/Madrid"
}
                

y la diferencia me da 20 días, lo cual es incorrecto.

ese bigint tiene los millisegundos???

en que linea exactamente sale el error???

Claramente y no la de pike, tienes que transformar las dos fechas y no solo una de las fechas, A ver se me ocurre:
<?php

$bigint = 1709541650;

$fecha_inicio = date("Y-m-d", $bigint);

echo $fecha_inicio; // Output: 2024-03-04

Para luego:
// Obtener la fecha y hora actual
$currentDateTime = new DateTime(); //sutituir con la fecha final de la base de datos

// Convertir la fecha formateada a objeto DateTime
$dateObject = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $fecha_inicio);

// Calcular la diferencia entre las dos fechas
$difference = $currentDateTime->diff($dateObject);

echo $difference->format('%d días, %h horas, %i minutos, %s segundos');

// Output: 18 días, 0 horas, 0 minutos, 0 segundos

Link del Sandbox Online.

Lo consegui hacer de otra forma: $timeImplementation = round(((int)$task['date_completed'] - (int)$task['date_creation'] )/ (60*60*24))  ." días"; . Sin embargo, ahora tengo otro problema, y es que en otro apartado la fecha se guarda como un string tipo "2024-04-23" y tampoco consigo coger la diferncia. He probado con el metodo que me has puesto @Francisco pero no me la diferencia de manera correcta

Lo he conseguido, no se porque razón pero a la horas de ponerle el formato el %d me da un valor erróneo, he tenido que poner %a
